# Create a transparent wrapper class in C++ for a C-style object

Tags: c++, c, operator-overloading, raii

I want to implement a class in C++ whose purpose is implementing RAII mechanism for a C-style object.

Then, I need to be able to pass an instance of this class to all the C-style functions that receive the mentioned C-style object as argument. I know that this should be solved with `unique_ptr`, but I cannot use `C++11` for now. Anyway, I would like to understand how this should be made, regardless that there are better solutions.

I have several doubts regarding to which operators I must overload, and the difference beteween some of them.

Below is an example of code with the implementation I have made. I am specially confused with the operators 1 and 2 (what is the difference?)

I want to know if the code I have implemented covers all the use cases, I mean, all the scenarios where the C library could use the object. In addition, I would like to understand the difference between the operators 1 and 2.

## C-Style object

```
// Example: a C-style library called "clib" which use an object called "cobj":

struct cobj {
    int n;    
};

void clib_create_cobj(struct cobj **obj) {
    *obj = (struct cobj*)malloc(sizeof(cobj));
    (*obj)->n = 25;
}

void clib_release_cobj(struct cobj *obj) {
    free(obj);
}

void clib_doSomething(struct cobj *obj) {
    std::cout << obj->n << std::endl;
}
```

## C++ "transparent" wrapper

```
// My wrapper class for implementing RAII

class CobjWrapper {
    public:
        CobjWrapper(struct cobj *obj) : m_obj (obj) { }

        ~CobjWrapper() {
            if(m_obj != NULL) {
                clib_release_cobj(m_obj);
                m_obj = NULL;
            }
        }


        operator struct cobj* () const {    // (1)
            return m_obj;
        }

        struct cobj& operator * () {        // (2)
            return *m_obj;
        }

        struct cobj** operator & () {       // (3)
            return &m_obj;
        }

        struct cobj* operator->() {     // (4)
            return m_obj;
        }

    private:
        struct cobj *m_obj;

};
```

## The main method

```
// The main method:

int main() {
  struct cobj *obj = NULL;

  clib_create_cobj(&obj);

  CobjWrapper w(obj);
  clib_doSomething(w);

  return 0;
}
```

The above source can be tested here:

http://cpp.sh/8nue3

Comment: Could you please formulate a clear question? Do you want to know the difference between (1) and (2)? Right now, you aren’t really asking anything but just say what you don’t know.

Comment: If you're going to implement RAII, you should know what *The rule of three/five/zero* is. Anyways, there's already `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter for this.

Comment: FYI: C++98 had `std::auto_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an *implicit cast*

```
operator struct cobj* () const {    // (1)
```

with example usage

```
CobjWrapper wrapper = /**/;

struct cobj* obj = wrapper;
```

whereas the following is the unary `operator *`

```
struct cobj& operator * () {        // (2)
```

with example usage

```
CobjWrapper wrapper = /**/;

struct cobj& obj = *wrapper;
```

BTW, I would completely hide the C struct, something like:

```
class CobjWrapper {

    struct ObjDeleter
    {
        void operator()(cobj *obj) const { clib_release_cobj(obj); }
    };

    public:
        CobjWrapper()
        {
             cobj *obj = nullptr;
             clib_create_cobj(&obj);
             m_obj.reset(obj);
        }

        void doSomething() { clib_doSomething(m_obj.get()); }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<cobj, ObjDeleter> m_obj;
};
```